# Amadeus flight offer search does not finish [SWIFT API] Is it a bug?

Tags: swift, http-get, amadeus

I have searched but didn't find anything. Maybe this is a very common issue in HTTP requests.

I use **amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get** function. The returned results are in the completion handler, either an error or the JSON data. However, when I call this function a number of times (using **Timer** and **LoopRun**) to search a number of Origin-Destination pairs, some of the call were not finished: the program never ran into the completion handler. I think, no matter what happened, at least the completion handler should be executed so that I know what errors occur. Is this a common observation for HTTP request? or is this a bug in Amadeus API? or Amadeus API server sometimes misses requests? Or did I miss anything?  Thanks in advance!

Btw, I know the 100ms limit on request rate. That's why I used Timer and LoopRun to send the request.

[Update]

I did more debugging and found one more issue. The source code of the API popped up an error:

In process() of Request.swift,

```
private func process(request: NSMutableURLRequest,
                  onCompletion: @escaping AmadeusResponse) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        var amadeusResponse: Response?
        var amadeusError: ResponseError?

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            // got a valid HTTP answer
            amadeusResponse = Response(response: httpResponse, data: data!)
            // Error could be either nil (200 OK) or enum value
            amadeusError = amadeusResponse!.getErrorCode()
        } else {
            // no HTTP answer: network problem
            amadeusResponse = nil
            amadeusError = ResponseError.returnedError(error!)
        }
        onCompletion(amadeusResponse, amadeusError)
    })
    task.resume()
}
In process() of Request.swift,
```

It pops up an error `"Thread 8: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"` at line `amadeusResponse = Response(response: httpResponse, data: data!)`

At this time, there is an error of "request time out". However, the code still forcefully unwrap the `data`, which is `nil`. For some reason, `if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse` does not screen out this error scenario.

But this still does not replicate my original observation that the completion handler is not called.

Comment: ##Whoever downvoted this question, can you give a reason? If you think this is a trivial question, or have been asked, please say something.

Comment: Hi @Feng. I don't know who downvoted your question but I think it's very interesting. That is correct, the completion handler must be always called. If that is not the case, it could be because the server is not answering so the handler is not called until a timeout comes. Maybe that could be the reason why you are getting the fatal error when receiving empty data . Did you check if that nil comes with a 200 response? (httpResponse.statusCode). Have you been able to reproduce the same behavior using other client? (curl for example)

Comment: @alnacle Thanks for your questions. Yes. the nil data comes with a 200 code (which suggests a successful request, right?). At the same time, error says "request timed out".

Comment: Getting a 200 response without data is super weird. I would love to debug that. Could you please try to print out the response? If you get a timeout is because the server is not answering (too many requests?).

Comment: I saw a long description of the error. But I'm not familiar with HTTP requests. I will spend sometime later today on that. I will spend sometime later today on that and let you know what I find out. it doesn't show up every time. 

But what happens more is that, the completion handler is not even called. Could you take a look into that as well? I used Timer and LoopRun to send request periodically (one second per request)